# Command runs in commandline but not in a BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a one liner batch command that sorts files by date and then deletes everything but the last 10. This command runs just fine when I run it in a CMD window. However, when I place it in a BAT file, I get errors.

Command (works OK in CMD window):

```
for /f "skip=10 delims=" %A in ('dir /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c *.jpg ^2^>nul') do del %A
```

Errors I get if trying to run it in a batch file:

```
Q:\Testbk>test1
-d was unexpected at this time.

Q:\Testbk>for /f "skip=10 delims=" -d /b /o:-d /t:c *.jpg ^2^>nul") do del A
```

Any idea as to how to fix it to run in a BAT file would be very much appreciated.

Comment: From the "for /?" help screen: `To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable`

Comment: Yes. Isn't bash-- I mean batch.. scripting awesome?

Comment: I am an idiot. Many tx!

Comment: Don't feel bad.  I am an idiot too.  It took me 30 min to figure out and post my answer below, only to get the updated screen with Michael Burr's comment/answer.

Comment: Also remove the `^` before the `2` as that is not required.

Answer (score 2):

You need %%A in the batch file.  I changed your original batch-file code to type rather than delete

```
for /f "skip=4 delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:-d /b /o:-d /t:c *.jpg 2^>nul') do type "%%A"
```

because I didn't want to delete my files.